# Insert child records all at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_links, -> { includes(:task).order("tasks.name") }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_links

class TaskLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :task

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :task_links
```

I want to create an after_create callback that will automatically create all task_links for all active projects and the newly created task.  I can do this by looping over the active projects and creating a task_link for each, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to do this?  Preferably with one big insert command instead of xxx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd need to use an `after_create` to do this, because I think a `before_create` would work quite well. With a `before_create`, you can save all of your `task_links` when your new `task` is saved.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :task_links

  before_create :create_task_links

  def create_task_links
    # I'm assuming that the where below satisfies "all active projects"
    Project.where(active: true).find_each do |proj|
      # build only creates objects but does not save them to your database
      self.task_links.build(project: proj)
    end
  end
end
```